# 2 things that wont work under windows 7 (works win 10)

Tags: delphi, touch, vcl

I have a simple form object that contains a button that I am using to replace scroll bars on a grid. The idea is to add this to the grid and the user has a nice big touch friendly button to use instead of a scroll bar. Everything is done and working fine on my win 10 dev system but I have discovered 2 things don't work under win 7. Unfortunately the target system for this app is win7 embedded.

1. The button does not receive touch events using the OnMouseMove handler.
   I am using "RegisterTouchWindow(sh.Handle, TWF_WANTPALM);" to get these messages.
2. AlphaBlendValue not working. I have the form fade itself out when not in use but I cant get it to work on the target system. I have another part of the software where I do something very similar and it works fine under win 7 - the only difference is in that case its a visually created form.

Code - Omitted what I think is irrelevant.

```
TLFScrollThumb = class(TForm)
private
  sh: TButton;
  timer: TTimer;
  Fgrid: TAdvStringGrid;
  FInternalAlign: Boolean;
  tmpTopLeftChangeEvt: TnotifyEvent;
  DelayFadeOut: integer;
  procedure ThumbMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
  procedure MoveControl(AControl: TControl; const X, Y: Integer);
  procedure TimerTimer(Sender: TObject);
  procedure Setgrid(const Value: TAdvStringGrid);
  procedure DoTopLeftChanged(Sender: TObject);
protected
  procedure DoShow; override;
public
  property grid: TAdvStringGrid read Fgrid write Setgrid;
  procedure SetBounds(ALeft, ATop, AWidth, AHeight: Integer); override;
  procedure Init;
  constructor CreateThumb(g: TAdvStringGrid);
  destructor Destroy; override;
end;

constructor TLFScrollThumb.CreateThumb(g: TAdvStringGrid);
begin
  Fgrid := NIL;
  inherited CreateNew(g);
  Width := 50;
  Height := 30;
  BorderStyle := TFormBorderStyle.bsNone;
  FInternalAlign := False;
  Align := alCustom;
  DelayFadeOut := 1000;

  sh := TButton.Create(self);
  sh.Parent := self;
  sh.Align := alClient;
  sh.Visible := true;
  sh.OnMouseMove := ThumbMove;

  timer := TTimer.Create(self);
  timer.Enabled := true;
  timer.Interval := 50;
  timer.OnTimer := TimerTimer;

  grid := g;
end;

procedure TLFScrollThumb.Init; 
begin
  AlphaBlend := true;
  AlphaBlendValue := THUMB_ALPHA_DEFAULT;
  RegisterTouchWindow(sh.Handle, TWF_WANTPALM);
end;

procedure TLFScrollThumb.ThumbMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X,  Y: Integer);
begin
  if AlphaBlendValue <> 1 then
  begin
    if AlphaBlendValue <> THUMB_ALPHA_DEFAULT then
    begin
      DelayFadeOut := 1000;
      AlphaBlendValue := THUMB_ALPHA_DEFAULT;
    end;
    Timer.Enabled := true;
    if (ssLeft in Shift) or (ssTouch in Shift) then // only move it when Left-click is down
      MoveControl(self, X, Y);
  end;
end;

procedure TLFScrollThumb.TimerTimer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if DelayFadeOut > 0 then
    DelayFadeOut := DelayFadeOut - Timer.Interval
  else
    AlphaBlendValue := AlphaBlendValue - 3;
  if AlphaBlendValue < THUMB_ALPHA_LOW_DEFAULT then
    Timer.Enabled := false;
end;

procedure TLFScrollThumb.SetBounds(ALeft, ATop, AWidth, AHeight: Integer);
begin
  if assigned(FGrid) then
  begin
    if ((grid.VisibleRowCount / grid.RowCount) > 0.5) or (grid.RowCount < 5) then
      AlphaBlendValue := 1
    else
      AlphaBlendValue := THUMB_ALPHA_DEFAULT;
    ATop :=  grid.FixedRowHeight + Round((grid.Clientheight - grid.FixedRowHeight - Height) * ((grid.TopRow-1) / ((grid.RowCount-1) - grid.VisibleRowCount)));
    if ATop < grid.FixedRowHeight then
      ATop := grid.FixedRowHeight;
    inherited SetBounds(grid.Width - Width, ATop, AWidth, AHeight);
  end
  else
    inherited SetBounds(ALeft, ATop, AWidth, AHeight);
end;
```

Usage...

```
  tmp := TLFScrollThumb.CreateThumb(g);
  tmp.Parent := g;
  tmp.init; // Must happen after the parent is set
  tmp.Show;
```

Comment: The next step is for you to do some debugging. It looks like you are asking us to do that. Why wouldn't you debug your program?

Comment: I have debugged this and it works fine on windows 10! I am hoping someone might have some clues as to why these specific issues are different between operating systems. As Delphi does not have any remote debugging ability I would very much like to avoid setting up a windows 7 dev system to solve this.

Comment: Delphi has remote debugging ability - http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Overview_of_Remote_Debugging

Comment: Delphi does have remote debugging. If you are targeting Windows 7 it is folly to attempt that without good development and debugging tools. Don't pretend that you can make progress by attempting to use Stack Overflow as a remote debugger. I've voting to close this question on these grounds.

Comment: Delphi has remote debugging, but you could also setup a VMWare with windows 7 and install delphi and your project there if you find this easier

Comment: I think it is a valid question to ask, whether somebody has an idea what the problem could be. I for one have to answer "no" to this question though. (Actually this should be split into two questions because there are two different issues that are unlikely to have the same cause.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delphi makes form transparent by (Amongst other thing) setting the WS_EX_LAYERED extended window style.

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff700543(v=vs.85).aspx) :

> Windows 8:  The WS_EX_LAYERED style is supported for top-level windows
>   and child windows. Previous Windows versions support WS_EX_LAYERED
>   only for top-level windows.

So your form is most likely not a top-level window.

Comment: From your comment I though I would test changing it to a visually (IDE) built form and this solved my touch problem but not the transparency issue. Other than creating the forms components from a resource I don't see what the difference is. One difference is that I was using CreateNew rather than Create but all that appears to do is set some defaults that I would assume to be the same as a resourced form.

Comment: The problem with the transparency is that I have to set the parent of the form so that the realignment works. This makes it a child window and stops support for WS_EX_LAYERED on windows 7.

Comment: I believe it is not required to be a child window, though I need to admit that would require quite a bit more code to synchronize its position with its "phylosophical" parent and might be more flickery.